# C++ how do i print objects in which i have entered data from an array of objects instead of printing all objects

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, object

I have an assignment to create a student record system in which i have to enter name, address and cgpa of students. I have created an array of object of size 20 and in each object i get name, address and cgpa from user. Now, it is not compulsory for user to enter data of all 20 objects instead it is dependent on user of how many records he want to enter. I create a function to show only entered records but the problem is it also shows records in which user has not entered any record.
(sorry for my bad English).

```
    void Input(){
    int i,c;
    string n,a;
    cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      Enter Name of the Student : ";
    cin >> n;
    set_name(n);
    cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      Enter ID of the Student : ";
    cin >> i;
    set_id(i);
    cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      Enter CGPA of the Student : ";
    cin >> c;
    set_cgpa(c);
    cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      Enter Address of the Student : ";
    cin >> a;
    set_address(a);
}

void Output(Student s[], int const){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
            cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      The Name of Student is " << s[i].get_name() << "." << endl;
            cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      The ID of Student is " << s[i].get_id() << "." << endl;
            cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      The CGPA of Student is " << s[i].get_cgpa() << "." << endl;
            cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t      The Address of Student is " << s[i].get_address() << "." << endl << endl << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}

int main(){
Student s[20];
int option;
for(int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i++){
    system("cls");
    s[i].drawmenu();
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t Enter An Option : ";
    cin >> option;
    if(option == 1){
        s[i].Input();
    }
    else if(option == 2){
        s[i].Output(s,20);
    }
    else if(option == 3){
        s[i].Search(s,20);
    }
    else if(option == 4){
        s[i].Update(s,20);
    }
    else if(option == 5){
        s[i].Delete(s,20);
    }
    else if(option == 6){
        break;
    }
    else if(option != 1 || option != 2 || option != 3 || option != 4 || option != 5 || option != 6){
        cout << endl << "\t\t\t\t    Entered Option is Not Valid." << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
}
return 1;
```

}

Comment: Can you count how many records the user has entered, store this number and then instead of counting from 0-19, count from 0-<whatever number>. I am not giving you any more help than that. Nobody helped me do homework questions when i was a kid.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I figured it out :)